# codename one i want to create a list of 10 items with icons and a checkbox if an item is selected

Tags: codenameone

Any idea with list style to use...the items are only 10 so I don't want to use an infinite container

As shown below

[image: example sreenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest [avoiding lists](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/avoiding-lists.html). Just use a Box Layout Y container and MultiButton in checkbox mode to implement this UI. You can add 10 components into a BoxLayout.Y container to create this.

Alternatively you can use [CheckBoxList](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/button-lists.html). I haven't played with it much myself but it might be more convenient depending on the type of data you need to follow.